# Switching to LuaLaTeX fails: Failed to load "luaotfload" module "database"

Tags: luatex, texstudio

I want to switch from plain LaTeX to LuaLaTeX. Unfortunately, I get an error right at the beginning:

```
$ lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode mwe.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (MiKTeX 23.5)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1


luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load "luaotfload" module "database".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "...ktex-texmf/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:204: module 'lua-uni-case' not found:".
luaotfload | load :     × "no field package.preload['lua-uni-case']".
luaotfload | load :     × "[kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'lua-uni-case'".

stack traceback:
    .../share/miktex-texmf/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:200: in upvalue 'loadmodule'
    .../share/miktex-texmf/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:275: in local 'initialize'
    .../share/miktex-texmf/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:330: in field 'main'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. I am using TeXstudio 4.2.1 with MikTeX Console 4.9 and this MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: lua-uni-case.lua is from the lua-uni-algos package. Check that it is installed an up-to-date (check for updates in user *and* admin mode, if you have a multi-user installation.

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer. This package was missing. Apparently the on-the-fly-installation is not working, or I am misunderstanding it.

Comment: It is my understanding that the MiKTeX on-the-fly only works when a package (or document class) specifically requests another missing package. It does not repair things that "are expected to be there" especially if not `*.sty` file. Am I correct?

Comment: @rallg no.  If you request a sty on-the-fly will kick in. The problem is that is that MiKTeX can't detect if lua files are requested and missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I understand that. But my above comment was poorly stated. Thanks for the clarification. It is important for the OP's question.